# Where to obtain full set of IPIP items on the internet?

Tags: personality, ipip

I heard that IPIP project consists of 2600 public domain questions.
Where I can find download those questions?
Is there any web address?

Comment: Searching for IPIP through Google answered both of your questions for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPIP website provides what I think is a complete list of the items:

There is a a table of contents here: http://ipip.ori.org/newIPIPitemsTOC.htm

and this appears to be a complete list of items: http://ipip.ori.org/new2413Items.htm